# Top level solution to rename AWS bucket item's folder names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've inherited a project at work.  Its essentially a niche content repository, and we use S3 to store the content.  The project was severely outdated, and I'm in the process of a thorough update.

For some unknown and undocumented reason, the content is stored in an AWS S3 bucket with the pattern `web_cl_000000$DB_ID$CONTENT_NAME`  So, one particular folder can be named `web_cl_0000003458zyxwv`.  This makes no sense, and requires a bit of transformation logic to construct a URL to serve up the content!

I can write a Python script using the `boto3` library to do an item-by-item rename, but would like to know if there's a faster way to do so.  There are approximately 4M items in that bucket, which will take quite a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't possible, because the folders are an illusion derived from the strings between `/` delimiters in the object keys.

> Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. **Amazon S3 does this by using key name prefixes for objects.** (emphasis added)
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

The console contributes to the illusion by allowing you to "create" a folder, but all that actually does is create a 0-byte object with `/` as its last character, which the console will display as a folder whether there are other objects with that prefix or not, making it easier to upload objects manually with some organization.

But any tool or technique that allows renaming folders in S3 will in fact be making a copy of each object with the modified name, then deleting the old object, because S3 does not actually support rename or move, either -- objects in S3, including their key and metadata, are actually immutable.  Any "change" is handled at the API level with a copy/overwrite or copy-then-delete.

Worth noting, S3 should be able to easily sustain 100 such requests per second, so with asynchronous requests or multi-threaded code, or even several processes each handling a shard of the keyspace, you should be able to do the whole thing in a few hours.

Note also that the *less sorted* (more random) the new keys are in the requests, the harder you can push S3 during a mass-write operation like this.  Sending the requests so that the new keys are in lexical order will be the most likely scenario in which you might see `503 Slow Down` errors... in which case, you just back off and retry... but if the new keys are not ordered, S3 can more easily accommodate a large number of requests.

Comment: I can't say that I'm surprised by your response, as that is basically what I understood from reading the docs.  I was hoping I was wrong.  Looks like the best solution would be to save the bucket/folder name as a db field for the legacy entity and move forward with a more sane naming scheme.